# Beginner HTML questions

Tags: html, mysql, css, twitter-bootstrap, jsp

So this is more of a design/how to question.

I am very new to HTML, and have used CSS only sparingly in the past.  I'm creating a J2EE web app just as a practice exercise for personal use.  As of now, everything works and looks fine.  Registration, login, MySQL storage and queries for allowing login, and general app navigation, everything's good.

But I'm trying to add a Bootstrap theme from Bootswatch on a separate identical jsp for testing the design, and design is getting kind of borked on the registration page.  The input boxes should be vertically stacked on top of each other with some nice spacing, which they are without the theme.  But once that's added in, they revert to looking awkwardly horizontal.

All of the HTML came from a free code snippet, so again, it's like greek to me (which is why I'm trying to learn it by doing this project) Does anyone have any ideas on how I would fix that?

Here is what is currently in the jsp:

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"
  import = "in.techyari.example.model.User"   

 %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- <link class="cssdeck" rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"> -->
<link class="cssdeck" rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" class="cssdeck">
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="default.css"> -->
</head>
<body>


<div class="" id="loginModal">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h3>Have an Account?</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="well">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li class="active"><a href="#login" data-toggle="tab">Login</a></li>
                <li><a href="#create" data-toggle="tab">Create Account</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane active in" id="login">
                    <form class="form-horizontal" action='' method="POST">
                        <fieldset>
                            <div id="legend">
                                <legend class="">Login</legend>
                            </div>    
                            <div class="control-group">
                                <!-- Username -->
                                <label class="control-label"  for="username">Username</label>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="" class="input-xlarge">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="control-group">
                                <!-- Password-->
                                <label class="control-label" for="password">Password</label>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="" class="input-xlarge">
                                </div>
                            </div>


                            <div class="control-group">
                                <!-- Button -->
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <button class="btn btn-success">Login</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                    </form>                
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="create">
                    <form id="tab">
                        <label>Full Name</label>
                        <input type="text" value="" class="input-xlarge">
                        <label>Email    </label>
                        <input type="text" value="" class="input-xlarge">
                        <label>Passowrd</label>
                        <input type="text" value="" class="input-xlarge">
                        <label>Gender</label>
                        <input type="text" value="" class="input-xlarge">
                        <label>Birthdate</label>
                        <input type="text" value="" class="input-xlarge">
<!--                        <textarea value="Smith" rows="3" class="input-xlarge"> -->
<!--                        </textarea> -->

                        <div>
                            <button class="btn btn-primary">Create Account</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>

<script class="cssdeck" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script class="cssdeck" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

In JSP this is how you can use JSTL tags to format href attributes (Download the latest JSTL from [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/taglibs/standard/) and unpack the compressed file. Then simply copy the JAR files in the distribution's 'lib' directory to your application's webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\lib directory):

include this in your .jsp file:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
```

and format your links and scripts located on your disk as:

```
<link class="cssdeck" rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value='css/bootstrap.min.css'/>">
```

So basically your .jsp page should look like this:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
         pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"
         import = "az.quiz.model.User"

        %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>


    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <!-- <link class="cssdeck" rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"> -->
      <link class="cssdeck" rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value='css/bootstrap.min.css'/>">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" class="cssdeck">
      <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value='default.css'/>"> -->
      <script class="cssdeck" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script class="cssdeck" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>


    <div class="" id="loginModal">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h3>Have an Account?</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="well">
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="active"><a href="#login" data-toggle="tab">Login</a></li>
            <li><a href="#create" data-toggle="tab">Create Account</a></li>
          </ul>
          <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane active in" id="login">
              <form class="form-horizontal" action='' method="POST">
                <fieldset>
                  <div id="legend">
                    <legend class="">Login</legend>
                  </div>
                  <div class="control-group">
                    <!-- Username -->
                    <label class="control-label"  for="username">Username</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                      <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="" class="input-xlarge">
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="control-group">
                    <!-- Password-->
                    <label class="control-label" for="password">Password</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                      <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="" class="input-xlarge">
                    </div>
                  </div>


                  <div class="control-group">
                    <!-- Button -->
                    <div class="controls">
                      <button class="btn btn-success">Login</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </fieldset>
              </form>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="create">
              <form id="tab">
                <label>Full Name</label>
                <input type="text" value="" class="input-xlarge">
                <label>Email    </label>
                <input type="text" value="" class="input-xlarge">
                <label>Passowrd</label>
                <input type="text" value="" class="input-xlarge">
                <label>Gender</label>
                <input type="text" value="" class="input-xlarge">
                <label>Birthdate</label>
                <input type="text" value="" class="input-xlarge">
                <!--                        <textarea value="Smith" rows="3" class="input-xlarge"> -->
                <!--                        </textarea> -->

                <div>
                  <button class="btn btn-primary">Create Account</button>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

And why do you keep your scripts outside `<html>` tags?

Comment: Thanks for the response man.  Again, very new to HTML, CSS, and scripts as well.  This is more just me tinkering trying to get things to work, and learning at the same time.  It's just that that code was a free snippet, and I didn't even know where to start trying correct the design problem I was facing.  Honestly, HTML and CSS is pretty overwhelming to me, and this is just a simple login page.  I tried doing what you posted, and it still doesn't work.  I guess I just need to keep tinkering.